# set default filter in gfile open dialog

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using `gWidgets2tcltk` to produce a simple `gfile()` open dialog with `filter=` to select only CSV files.

**How can I make this CSV filter the default filter?**

This *almost* does what I want:

```
library(gWidgets2tcltk) # v. 1.0.5
library(gWidgets2)      # v. 1.0.7

gfile(text='Select CSV for input',
      type='open',
      initial.filename = NULL,
      initial.dir='D:/workspace/folder',
      toolkit=guiToolkit(name='tcltk'),
      filter=c('CSV'='csv') )
```

The only issue is that the CSV filter is not selected by default -- it has to be selected by user via drop-down.

[image]

The documentation under `?gfile` is sparse.  Literally:

> A filter specifiation. This can be a named character vector of file
>   extensions or something toolkit specific. Here are some examples:
>
> - characterc("csv"="csv","txt"="txt")
> - RGtk2 Something like   list("All files" = list(patterns = c("*")),
>        "R files" = list(patterns = c("*.R", "*.Rdata")),
>        "text files" = list(mime.types = c("text/plain"))
>       )
> - tcltk
> - Qt

I'm on R 3.3.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: `filter = list("CSV" = list(patterns = "*.csv"))` works for me. It appears to be selecting the first group by lexicographic order, so if you also need the *All Files* option, you could do something like add a space before *All*, e.g. `filter = list("CSV" = list(patterns = "*.csv"), " All files" = list(patterns = "*"))`.

Comment: That works for me too.  I would accept your comment as an answer.  Thanks!